# Harmonics explanation in terms of physics

Tags: sound-theory

I am an audio engineering student. Can anybody explain what exactly harmonics is in terms of physics , not in terms of music?

Comment: Harmonics are frequencies that are integer multiples of a base (or *fundamental*) frequency. Overtones are more generally any resonant frequencies related to the fundamental. See the Music SE (https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24882/whats-the-difference-between-overtones-and-harmonics#24897)

Comment: Jim - if you could post that as an answer, I'd upvote it. The existing answer by physics guy is fundamentally incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

harmonics are the relative frequencies that are a multiple or divisible by a number to create a ratio that is not too high or too low as to cause beating that is too fast or too slow. When the frequencies are too close together for example it will have a very fast beating which sounds unpleasant. So if you take a frequency and add in all the frequencies that don't cause fast beating relative to each other starting with an arbitrary frequency and add them together you will get a frequencies relative harmonics.....